# syntax of data dictionary concept in angular is correct or not?

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to get the values by using **data-dictionary** concept but I am confused how I can write it down what was its proper syntax.

```js
$scope.listDetails = {
        "venue-1": {
            "id": "1",
            "venue": "venue-1",
            "membershiptype": "RG11EP",
            "AbsoluteImageUrl": "http://www.sporta.co.il/include/items/102.jpg",
            "ImageFileName": "102.jpg",
            "address": "Golds Gym,Kalyannagar",
            "AbsoluteImageUrl1": "https://amidtheimaginary.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/3-star-rating.jpg",
            "ImageFileName1": "3-star-rating.jpg",
            "description": "Gold’s Gym started in Venice California in 1965, and soon became the hotbed for the development of training techniques, equipment and nutritional concepts that formed the foundation for the modern fitness revolution.",
            "email": "goldsgym.123@gmail.com",
            "phoneno": "+91-7829439349",
            "postcode": "560043",
            "upgrade": "Upgrade-membershilp"
        },
        "venue-2": {
            "id": "2",
            "venue": "venue-2",
            "membershiptype": "RG11ER",
            "AbsoluteImageUrl": "http://www.sporta.co.il/include/items/102.jpg",
            "ImageFileName": "102.jpg",
            "address": "Dance School,hebbal",
            "AbsoluteImageUrl1": "https://amidtheimaginary.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/3-star-rating.jpg",
            "ImageFileName1": "3-star-rating.jpg",
            "description": "This dance shool is really nice.You will definitly like it.",
            "email": "danceshool@gmail.com",
            "phoneno": "+91-7829439347",
            "postcode": "560094",
            "upgrade": "Upgrade-membershilp"
        },
    };
```

Any one just say it correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s Correct, but this is a javascript concept. Javascript objects are key-value pairs (dictionary). Please note that the quotes on the key is optional `id: "2"` instead of `"id" : "2"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help